# how can create a deeply nested object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested

I want to create nested object in deeply way. What I'm trying to create is a grouped summary object from the array of nested JSON objects with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "193",
        "type": "Dental Provider",
        "classification": "Dentis",
        "specialization": "General Practice",
        "definition": "definition1",
        "notes": "[7/1/2003: new]",
        "individual": "individual"},
    {
        "id": 11,
        "code": "207",
        "type": "Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians",
        "classification": "Anesthesiology",
        "specialization": "Pediatric Anesthesiology",
        "definition": "defin_2",
        "individual": "individual"}]
```

Expected:

```
result = {
    "invidual": {
        "Dental Provider": {
            "Dentis":{
                "General Practice":{
                    id: 1,
                    code: "193",
                    definition: "definition1",
                    individual: "individual",
                    type: "Dental Provider",
                    classification: "Dentist",
                    specialization: "General Practice"},
"invidual": {
        "Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians": {
            "Anesthesiology":{
                "Pediatric Anesthesiology":{
                    id: 11,
                    code: "207",
                    definition: "defin_2",
                    individual: "individual",
                    type: "Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians",
                    classification: "Anesthesiology",
                    specialization: "Pediatric Anesthesiology"}
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO (there are **hundreds** of questions like this), and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let result = taxonomies.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.individual] = c[v.individual] || {};                         
  c[v.individual][v.type] = c[v.individual][v.type] || {};   
  c[v.individual][v.type][v.classification] = c[v.individual][v.type][v.classification] || {};    
  c[v.individual][v.type][v.classification][v.specialization] = v
console.log(result)
```